# Como retornar data e hora mais próxima da informada pelo usuario

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho uma tabela com uma lista de locais por onde um caminhão passou com a data/hora de sua entrada e saída

```
+----+------------------+-----------+---------------+
| ID |   DATA E HORA    |   LOCAL   | ENTRADA/SAIDA |
+----+------------------+-----------+---------------+
|  1 | 28/01/2017 07:27 | FABRICA   | Entrada       |
|  2 | 28/01/2017 09:00 | FABRICA   | Saida         |
|  3 | 29/01/2017 00:02 | REVENDA 1 | Entrada       |
|  4 | 29/01/2017 04:00 | REVENDA 1 | Saida         |
|  5 | 29/01/2017 08:00 | REVENDA 2 | Entrada       |
|  6 | 29/01/2017 10:00 | REVENDA 2 | Saida         |
|  7 | 29/01/2017 20:00 | FABRICA   | Entrada       |
|  8 | 29/01/2017 23:00 | FABRICA   | Saida         |
+----+------------------+-----------+---------------+
```

Preciso fazer uma QUERY que com uma data/hora informada pelo usuário, retorne onde o caminhão estava naquele momento.

Existe alguma função que retorne a ocorrência de data/hora mais próxima a partir de uma informada na QUERY? Existe uma forma mais eficiente de se fazer? Como? Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: O que é para acontecer se for informado `29/01/2017 06:00` com os dados do seu exemplo acima?

Comment: É para encontrar onde ele estava nesse horário, daí vou calcular o tempo em que ele ficou nesse lugar

Comment: Boa pergunta, nunca tive um problema desse mais fiquei curioso com a solução!

Comment: Repetindo a pergunta do @Bacco, deve retornar REVENDA 1 ou REVENDA 2? Porque ambos locais estavam a 2h de distância de `29/01/2017 06:00`, e nesta tabela não existe um campo "distância", por tanto o cálculo é feito usando o horário.

Comment: Ah perdão, não tinha percebido isso. Se o valor não estiver entre uma Entrada e Saída ele vai estar em Rota, eu não pensei nisso quando "modelei" o banco descupe. Existe alguma forma de contornar isso?

Comment: @Lucas tem duas saídas boas: uma é sair desse conceito de uma entrada separada da saída, e por tudo em duas linhas, e tratar a rota separada da "presença". A outra é deixar como está e mostrar a data imediatamente antes e a data imediatamente depois, e ao exibir, se for igual o local, mostra um só, se for diferente mostra "entre local1 e local2". De qualquer forma, precisa [edit] a questão e deixar claras as regras, para que as respostas possam refletir a necessidade completa. Cuidado para não alterar a ponto de invalidar totalmente as respostas atuais.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode ordenar as datas, filtrar as datas anteriores a data informada e limitar a um registro o resultado. Como você não passou informações reais, como nome da tabela e campos, não tenho como escrever a SQL exata. Mas será algo desse tipo:

```
SELECT LOCAL FROM _TABELA WHERE DATA_FORNECIDA > DATA_E_HORA ORDER BY DATA_E_HORA LIMITE 1
```

Comment: fiz um teste aqui recriando essa tabela dele e rodando sua query e procurando por onde estava o veículo em '2017-01-29 00:03:00', mostrou FABRICA, quando a resposta desejada seria REVENDA 1

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que isto possa te ajudar :

```
    SELECT max(HORADOCAMINHAO), COD_CAMINHAO 
    FROM tabela
    WHERE
    DAT_SOLICITACAO < '2016-10-31 06:36:01.000'/*informe a data desejada*/ 
    and COD_CAMINHAO = 123
    GROUP BY COD_CAMINHAO

/*troque o que está dentro do() pela coluna que 
    informa a data, e informe as demais colunas desejadas 
    no GROUP BY */
```

Comment: No caso esse código é apenas dos registros, cada caminhão tem uma tabela separada

Answer (score 1):

Não existe INTERSECT para MySQL e foi preciso emular usando UNION ALL. Esse SQL a primeira vista parece esquisito, mas não é complicado, **e passa em todos os testes, localizando o local correto para cada horário**. Segue massa para o teste, a lógica e os testes propriamente ditos.

Primeiro foi criada uma tabela que reproduz essa que foi postada na pergunta.

```
CREATE TABLE `LISTA_LOCAIS` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `DATA_HORA` timestamp NOT NULL,
  `LOCAL` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `ENTRADA_SAIDA` varchar(10) NOT NULL
)
```

Em seguida criamos uma massa de testes idêntica a da tabela mostrada na pergunta.

```
INSERT INTO LISTA_LOCAIS(ID,DATA_HORA,LOCAL,ENTRADA_SAIDA) VALUES(1,'2017-01-28 07:27','FABRICA'   ,'Entrada');
INSERT INTO LISTA_LOCAIS(ID,DATA_HORA,LOCAL,ENTRADA_SAIDA) VALUES(2,'2017-01-28 09:00','FABRICA'   ,'Saida'  );
INSERT INTO LISTA_LOCAIS(ID,DATA_HORA,LOCAL,ENTRADA_SAIDA) VALUES(3,'2017-01-29 00:02','REVENDA 1' ,'Entrada');
INSERT INTO LISTA_LOCAIS(ID,DATA_HORA,LOCAL,ENTRADA_SAIDA) VALUES(4,'2017-01-29 04:00','REVENDA 1' ,'Saida'  );
INSERT INTO LISTA_LOCAIS(ID,DATA_HORA,LOCAL,ENTRADA_SAIDA) VALUES(5,'2017-01-29 08:00','REVENDA 2' ,'Entrada');
INSERT INTO LISTA_LOCAIS(ID,DATA_HORA,LOCAL,ENTRADA_SAIDA) VALUES(6,'2017-01-29 10:00','REVENDA 2' ,'Saida'  );
INSERT INTO LISTA_LOCAIS(ID,DATA_HORA,LOCAL,ENTRADA_SAIDA) VALUES(7,'2017-01-29 20:00','FABRICA'   ,'Entrada');
INSERT INTO LISTA_LOCAIS(ID,DATA_HORA,LOCAL,ENTRADA_SAIDA) VALUES(8,'2017-01-29 23:00','FABRICA'   ,'Saida'  );
```

Segue agora o SQL para fazer a busca do local em determinado horário:

```
SELECT LOCAL from (
  (SELECT LOCAL FROM LISTA_LOCAIS WHERE
ENTRADA_SAIDA='Entrada' AND 'SUA_TIMESTAMP_PESQUISADA' >= DATA_HORA ORDER BY DATA_HORA DESC LIMIT 2)
  UNION ALL 
  (SELECT LOCAL FROM LISTA_LOCAIS WHERE
ENTRADA_SAIDA='Saida' AND 'SUA_TIMESTAMP_PESQUISADA' <= DATA_HORA ORDER BY DATA_HORA ASC LIMIT 2)
) AS TABELA_UNIFICADA  GROUP BY LOCAL HAVING count(*) >= 2
```

Explicação:
Primeiro pega uma parte que casa com a entrada. Em seguida pega uma parte que casa com a saída. Faz a interseção dos dois. Perceba a sacada da ordenação decrescente para a entrada e ordenação ascendente para a saída para limitar bem os registros dessa interseção.

Seguem os testes:

```
-- TESTE 1:  REVENDA 1 em 2017-01-29 00:03:00
SELECT LOCAL from (
  (SELECT LOCAL FROM LISTA_LOCAIS WHERE
ENTRADA_SAIDA='Entrada' AND '2017-01-29 00:03:00' >= DATA_HORA ORDER BY DATA_HORA DESC LIMIT 2)
  UNION ALL 
  (SELECT LOCAL FROM LISTA_LOCAIS WHERE
ENTRADA_SAIDA='Saida' AND '2017-01-29 00:03:00' <= DATA_HORA ORDER BY DATA_HORA ASC LIMIT 2)
) AS TABELA_UNIFICADA  GROUP BY LOCAL HAVING count(*) >= 2


-- TESTE 2: FABRICA em 2017-01-28 08:00
SELECT LOCAL from (
  (SELECT LOCAL FROM LISTA_LOCAIS WHERE
ENTRADA_SAIDA='Entrada' AND '2017-01-28 08:00' >= DATA_HORA ORDER BY DATA_HORA DESC LIMIT 2)
  UNION ALL 
  (SELECT LOCAL FROM LISTA_LOCAIS WHERE
ENTRADA_SAIDA='Saida' AND '2017-01-28 08:00' <= DATA_HORA ORDER BY DATA_HORA ASC LIMIT 2)
) AS TABELA_UNIFICADA  GROUP BY LOCAL HAVING count(*) >= 2


-- TESTE 3: EM LUGAR NENHUM / CAMINHÃO EM ROTA em 2017-01-28 12:00 - não tem a entrada do local para esse período
SELECT LOCAL from (
  (SELECT LOCAL FROM LISTA_LOCAIS WHERE
ENTRADA_SAIDA='Entrada' AND '2017-01-28 12:00' >= DATA_HORA ORDER BY DATA_HORA DESC LIMIT 2)
  UNION ALL 
  (SELECT LOCAL FROM LISTA_LOCAIS WHERE
ENTRADA_SAIDA='Saida' AND '2017-01-28 12:00' <= DATA_HORA ORDER BY DATA_HORA ASC LIMIT 2)
) AS TABELA_UNIFICADA  GROUP BY LOCAL HAVING count(*) >= 2


-- TESTE 4: REVENDA 2 em 2017-01-29 08:00
SELECT LOCAL from (
  (SELECT LOCAL FROM LISTA_LOCAIS WHERE
ENTRADA_SAIDA='Entrada' AND '2017-01-29 08:00' >= DATA_HORA ORDER BY DATA_HORA DESC LIMIT 2)
  UNION ALL 
  (SELECT LOCAL FROM LISTA_LOCAIS WHERE
ENTRADA_SAIDA='Saida' AND '2017-01-29 08:00' <= DATA_HORA ORDER BY DATA_HORA ASC LIMIT 2)
) AS TABELA_UNIFICADA  GROUP BY LOCAL HAVING count(*) >= 2


-- TESTE 5: REVENDA 2 em 2017-01-29 09:00
SELECT LOCAL from (
  (SELECT LOCAL FROM LISTA_LOCAIS WHERE
ENTRADA_SAIDA='Entrada' AND '2017-01-29 09:00' >= DATA_HORA ORDER BY DATA_HORA DESC LIMIT 2)
  UNION ALL 
  (SELECT LOCAL FROM LISTA_LOCAIS WHERE
ENTRADA_SAIDA='Saida' AND '2017-01-29 09:00' <= DATA_HORA ORDER BY DATA_HORA ASC LIMIT 2)
) AS TABELA_UNIFICADA  GROUP BY LOCAL HAVING count(*) >= 2


-- TESTE 6: REVENDA 2 em 2017-01-29 10:00
SELECT LOCAL from (
  (SELECT LOCAL FROM LISTA_LOCAIS WHERE
ENTRADA_SAIDA='Entrada' AND '2017-01-29 10:00' >= DATA_HORA ORDER BY DATA_HORA DESC LIMIT 2)
  UNION ALL 
  (SELECT LOCAL FROM LISTA_LOCAIS WHERE
ENTRADA_SAIDA='Saida' AND '2017-01-29 10:00' <= DATA_HORA ORDER BY DATA_HORA ASC LIMIT 2)
) AS TABELA_UNIFICADA  GROUP BY LOCAL HAVING count(*) >= 2


-- TESTE 7: LUGAR NENHUM / CAMINHÃO EM ROTA em 2017-01-29 16:00
SELECT LOCAL from (
  (SELECT LOCAL FROM LISTA_LOCAIS WHERE
ENTRADA_SAIDA='Entrada' AND '2017-01-29 16:00' >= DATA_HORA ORDER BY DATA_HORA DESC LIMIT 2)
  UNION ALL 
  (SELECT LOCAL FROM LISTA_LOCAIS WHERE
ENTRADA_SAIDA='Saida' AND '2017-01-29 16:00' <= DATA_HORA ORDER BY DATA_HORA ASC LIMIT 2)
) AS TABELA_UNIFICADA  GROUP BY LOCAL HAVING count(*) >= 2


-- TESTE 8: FABRICA em 2017-01-29 20:00
SELECT LOCAL from (
  (SELECT LOCAL FROM LISTA_LOCAIS WHERE
ENTRADA_SAIDA='Entrada' AND '2017-01-29 20:00' >= DATA_HORA ORDER BY DATA_HORA DESC LIMIT 2)
  UNION ALL 
  (SELECT LOCAL FROM LISTA_LOCAIS WHERE
ENTRADA_SAIDA='Saida' AND '2017-01-29 20:00' <= DATA_HORA ORDER BY DATA_HORA ASC LIMIT 2)
) AS TABELA_UNIFICADA  GROUP BY LOCAL HAVING count(*) >= 2


-- TESTE 9: FABRICA em 2017-01-29 23:00
SELECT LOCAL from (
  (SELECT LOCAL FROM LISTA_LOCAIS WHERE
ENTRADA_SAIDA='Entrada' AND '2017-01-29 23:00' >= DATA_HORA ORDER BY DATA_HORA DESC LIMIT 2)
  UNION ALL 
  (SELECT LOCAL FROM LISTA_LOCAIS WHERE
ENTRADA_SAIDA='Saida' AND '2017-01-29 23:00' <= DATA_HORA ORDER BY DATA_HORA ASC LIMIT 2)
) AS TABELA_UNIFICADA  GROUP BY LOCAL HAVING count(*) >= 2


-- TESTE 10: LUGAR NENHUM  / CAMINHÃO EM ROTA  em 2017-01-29 23:10
SELECT LOCAL from (
  (SELECT LOCAL FROM LISTA_LOCAIS WHERE
ENTRADA_SAIDA='Entrada' AND '2017-01-29 23:10' >= DATA_HORA ORDER BY DATA_HORA DESC LIMIT 2)
  UNION ALL 
  (SELECT LOCAL FROM LISTA_LOCAIS WHERE
ENTRADA_SAIDA='Saida' AND '2017-01-29 23:10' <= DATA_HORA ORDER BY DATA_HORA ASC LIMIT 2)
) AS TABELA_UNIFICADA  GROUP BY LOCAL HAVING count(*) >= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Com esse select eu posso selecionar o local mais aproximado daquele caminhão no dado momento.

```
SELECT LOCAL, min( abs( UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATA_HORA) -  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('29-01-2017 05:00', '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s')))) AS PROVAVEL from lista_locais
GROUP BY LOCAL 
ORDER BY PROVAVEL LIMIT 1
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As 5 horas do dia 29/01/2017 ele esta mais próximo da revenda 1.

```
SELECT LOCAL, min( abs( UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATA_HORA) -  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('29-01-2017 08:30', '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s')))) AS PROVAVEL from lista_locais
GROUP BY LOCAL 
ORDER BY PROVAVEL LIMIT 1
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E as 8:30 do mesmo dia ele esta na revenda 2.